# Set amount of pictures with UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController, and I need to be able to upload multiple pictures, and set the max amount of pictures my user will be able to upload. How do I do that  ? (Using Swift 3)

Comment: No idea why this was closed. It seems like a quite well-defined, small-scope problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly not, the picker is only for single images or videos. You will need to create your own to simulate the normal photo album.

or 
you can use ELCImagePickerController.

Answer (score 0):

UIImagePickerController doesn't allow to pick multiple pictures. Use third party framework for it. For example:

[Fusuma](https://github.com/ytakzk/Fusuma)

[Paparazo](https://github.com/avito-tech/Paparazzo)